# How to make matplotlib display Chinese correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, chinese-locale

How to make matplotlib display Chinese correctly.
Thank you .

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib

from pylab import mpl

import pymysql

matplotlib.rcParams ['font.family'] = ['HGFS1_CNKI'] # Still show white square 



plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei']
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False



districts = ['鼓楼', '建邺', '栖霞', '雨花台', '秦淮', '玄武', '江宁', '浦口', '六合', '溧水', '高淳']
nums = [3172, 1733, 1973, 1372, 2434, 2246, 3338, 1435, 849, 942, 94]

plt.bar(range(len(nums)), nums, tick_label=districts)
plt.show()
```

sudo cp HGFS1_CNKI.TTF /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/

[image]

Comment: Did you look at this  [post](https://hoishing.medium.com/using-chinese-characters-in-matplotlib-5c49dbb6a2f7)?

Comment: Still show white square @Ahx